# How to resize Safari address bar on macOS Sierra or newer?

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra

It seems that the Safari address bar width is locked to a maximum size that may make some URL impossible to read, especially if the domain part is longer, like in many intranets, or when the the of the URL is longer and when it  contains essential information near the end.

[image: menu bar]

I fount no way to change the width of the bar using Customize Toolbar option.
I am using Safari 11 on macOS 10.13 (high-sierra) but I am pretty sure that the same problem would apply for macOS 10.12 (Sierra).

Comment: There is no setting available to change address bar width in Safari. The only thing that probably may help you is to turn off **Show Full Website address** option.
Go to `Settings -> Advanced` and uncheck it.

Comment: Those guys are crazy... I really would like to know why this is not available. Would you?

Comment: [Always show full URL in Safari address bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371473/always-show-full-url-in-safari-address-bar/371474#371474) basically comments under Nimesh's answer.

Answer (score 6):

1. Right-click on an empty area at the top of Safari’s window and select Customize Toolbar.
2. You’ll see two “flexible spaces” on each side of the URL bar. 2 tranparent boxes.
3. Remove these boxes (by dragging them out of the toolbar), and you should wind up with a larger URL entry area.

Comment: I reverted back from the behaviour because the the suggestions while editing URL take up the full page, hiding the content which I might have my eyes on. The suggestion box seems to be square with search bar's width.

Comment: This does not work on macOS 10.13. The Address bar stays the same width even when those _flexible space_ boxes are removed.

Comment: this only works for 'legacy' mode, ie when you have in _Preferences_ > _Tabs_ > _Tab Layout_: **Separate**. For **Compact** mode not working.

Answer (score -2):

Click default bar first, it will shorten the address bar, then build your own layout to you liking.