# Always show full URL in Safari address bar

Tags: macos, safari, customization, url

From the screenshot: notice we only see "github.com":

> [image]

Yes it is possible to see full path by actually selecting the URL:

> [image]

But I would like to see the full URL always - without that extra step. Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Open Safari Preferences window using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or by going to Menu bar → Safari → Preferences..., and go to the Advanced tab. Check **Show full website address**.

[image]

Once this setting is enabled, Safari will always show the complete address for the currently open webpage, even when the Smart Search Field is not in focus.

[image]

Comment: If I'd still be using Safari, I would be more interested in how you managed to have the URL field be so long/big? It is always much smaller for me.

Comment: @LangLangC Use View > Customize Toolbar to change which items appear (and don't appear) in the Toolbar. Doing so affects the length of the URL field.

Comment: @David Not for me. For this very page we're on it is always truncated after "-in-safari-address-ba…" Tried to remove all buttons (incl spacers), no change (and "Downloads" always popping back to the right of it, whether removed or put to the left…)

Comment: @LangLangC It works for me on Safari 12.1.2. Try adding a "flexible space" to your Toolbar, then reducing the size of the flexible space. When I do that, the URL space expands.

Comment: @LangLangC As mentioned by David, Customize toolbar "is" the setting you are looking for. I generally remove all the items (even the back forward buttons) from the toolbar, barring the address bar. You can use keyboard shortcut for all the actions.

Comment: Knowing the Safari version should help. @David mentions it works on Safari 12.1.2. I am running Safari 13.0.1 on Mojave and it works for me. This should work in pretty much any version of Safari.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to show the https:// or http:// prefix.  Any way to include that?

Answer (score 3):

Try Preferences / Advanced / Smart Search Field [ ] Show full website address:

[image]

(screenshot from Safari 11.1.2)