# Always show URLs in Safari's Tab Overview

Tags: macos, safari, customization, url

In the Tabs overview, notice that we see the page title but not the page URL.

[image: Screenshot of Safari that highlights 3 tabs with identical titles that are at completely different URLS]

In the screenshot above, I highlight three tabs with identical titles which are on completely different servers at different domains: localhost, a staging server, and production.

It's impossible for me to tell these apart in the Menu Bar → View → Show Tab Overview. How can I change Tab Overview to show the URL so I can differentiate these tabs? Is it possible?

—

Note: [Always show full URL in Safari address bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371473/always-show-full-url-in-safari-address-bar) is a similar but completely different question because it's trying to change a different part of the Safari interface.